Get the index of a selected edge in Blender 4 - Python
I am day one of trying to learn how to make custom interfaces for Blender. So far, so good apart from I'm struggling to get the selected edge's index so that I may invoke the loop cut tool. My code works, but the selected edge's index is always 0. Looking through the docs I'm drawing a blank, so have decided to ask for help.
I would like to get the edge index of the currently selected edge, and as a bonus I'd like to grey out the buttons if an object isnt in edit mode, but that can be tomorrow's project. I wont be greedy :)
EDIT: I've worked out how to detect edit mode and change my panel, so that bit at least is solved :)
What I've tried:
# makew this an add on
bl_info = {
    "name" : "Poly Modelling",
    "author" : "Andrew Larking",
    "version" : (0, 0, 1),
    "blender" : (4, 2, 3),
    "location" : "3D Viewport > Sidebar > Poly Modelling category",
    "description" : "My custom poly modelling panel",
    "category" : "Development",
}


# give Pythion access to Blender
import bpy

class VIEW3D_PT_my_UI(bpy.types.Panel):

    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    
    # add labels
    bl_label = "Poly Modelling"
    bl_category = "Poly Modelling"

    # overrides
    def loopcut(override, *, edge_index, number_cuts):
    cutting_data = {
        "number_cuts"  : number_cuts,
        "object_index" : 0,
        "edge_index"   : edge_index,
    }
    
    def draw(self, content):
        """define the layout of the panel"""

    def draw(self, context):
        """define the layout"""
        primitivesRowLabel = self.layout.row(align=True)
        primitivesRowLabel.label(text="Primitives")
        primitivesRow = self.layout.row(align=False)
        primitivesRow.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add", text="Cube")
        primitivesRow.operator("mesh.primitive_plane_add", text="Plane")
        primitivesRow.operator("mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add", text="Sphere")
        primitivesRowTwo = self.layout.row(align=False)
        primitivesRowTwo.operator("mesh.primitive_cylinder_add", text="Cylinder")
        primitivesRowTwo.operator("mesh.primitive_grid_add", text="Grid")
        
        
        faceOperatorsRowLabel = self.layout.row(align=True)
        faceOperatorsRowLabel.label(text="Face Operators")
        
        faceOperatorsRow = self.layout.row()
        faceOperatorsRow.operator("object.editmode_toggle", text="Object / Edit")
        faceOperatorsRow.operator("ops.mesh.loopcut_slide", text="Loop Cut")

        
# register
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(VIEW3D_PT_my_UI)
    
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(VIEW3D_PT_my_UI)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

